# Issues w/external sources

Tags: excel

i have a workbook that contains three external sources (excel workbooks) through connections and the below index, match formula is applied to the majority of the cells in the workbook.  after some time, the report has begun to boggle down my computer and there are less than a hundred line items in the workbook.  i would like some assistance with determining a possible alternative to pulling external sources.

```
=INDEX('C:\Users\NG8\OneDrive\Desktop\[ESR 121019.xlsx]ReportingProjStat'!$AC:$AC,MATCH(1,(B53='C:\Users\NG8\OneDrive\Desktop\[ESR 121019.xlsx]ReportingProjStat'!$B:$B)*(1='C:\Users\NG8\OneDrive\Desktop\[ESR 121019.xlsx]ReportingProjStat'!$E:$E),0))
```

Comment: Use Power Query

Comment: Your formula is looking in whole columns and there are over 1 million rows in an Excel sheet so that's probably bogging it down. You could try specifying the number of rows for it to check, if you have a rough idea of how much data is in the external files you could over estimate the number of rows to check, maybe like 250,000 or something. Otherwise, Power Query is an option like Ricardo mentioned.